# ¿Cómo hacer una búsqueda de un atributo en una lista de objetos en phyton?

Tags: python-3.x

Cordial saludo a todos lo que vean el post

Mi pregunta es la siguiente...

Estoy escribiendo un código en phyton en dónde estoy utilizando programación orientada a objetos, el tema es que yo estoy guardando un objeto en una lista en donde ese objeto tiene un atributo que es como un tipo de id o código, la idea es que cada vez que se cree un nuevo objeto se haga antes una verificación de que el código no exista, sin embargo no sé cómo acceder a ese atributo al momento de recorrer mi lista para verificar que efectivamente ese código no existe en la lista.
Adjunto el código
import Animal

```
f=[]
def Buy():
    t=("Chicken","Pig","Cow")
    c=input("animal's code: ")
    for x in f:
      **"Aquí haría la verificación sin embargo no sé como"**
    s=input("Price: ")
    w=input("Weight: ")
    tipe=input("What is the animal to buy: ").lower()
    o = True
    for s in t:
        if(s==tipo):
            o=True
    if(o):
        if(tipe=='chicken'):
            ts=input("¿Fattening or Laying").lower()
            e=input("age: ")
            a=Animal.Chicken(c,w,s)
            a.Chicken(ts,e)
            print(a.ToString())
            f.append(a)
        elif (tipe=='pig'):
            sex=input("sex: ")
            a=Animal.Pig(c,w,s)
            a.Pig(sex)
            print(a.ToString())
            f.append(a)
        elif (tipe=='cow'):
            mp=input("milker or production").lower()
            a=Animal.Cow(c,w,s)
            a.Cow(mp)
            print(a.ToString())
            f.append(a)
    print("Thanks for your bought")
def Sell():
    return 0
def Calculate():
    return 0
def Change():
    return 0
def Determ():
    return 0
s=True
d={'1': Buy, '2': Sell, '3': Calculate, '4': Change,'5':Determ}
while(s==True):
    print("""this the farm's menu
    1.register a purchase
    2.Register a sale
    3.Calculate profit
    4.Change age
    5.Determ
    6.exit
    """)
    a=input("Choose your option: ")
    if(a==6):
        s=False
    else:
        d[a]();
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes simplemente comprobar si el codigo ingresado existe en todos los objetos de f, justo con el mismo for que ya tienes hecho.

quedaría algo así.:

```
f=[]
def Buy():
    t=("Chicken","Pig","Cow")
    c=input("animal's code: ")
    exist = false
    for x in f:
        #cambia c.get("code") por la forma en que obtienes el codigo.
        #if x.get("code") == c:
        if x.code == c:
            exist = true

    if !exist:
        s=input("Price: ")
        w=input("Weight: ")
        tipe=input("What is the animal to buy: ").lower()
        o = True
        for s in t:
            if(s==tipo):
                o=True
        if(o):
            if(tipe=='chicken'):
                ts=input("¿Fattening or Laying").lower()
                e=input("age: ")
                a=Animal.Chicken(c,w,s)
                a.Chicken(ts,e)
                print(a.ToString())
                f.append(a)
            elif (tipe=='pig'):
                sex=input("sex: ")
                a=Animal.Pig(c,w,s)
                a.Pig(sex)
                print(a.ToString())
                f.append(a)
            elif (tipe=='cow'):
                mp=input("milker or production").lower()
                a=Animal.Cow(c,w,s)
                a.Cow(mp)
                print(a.ToString())
                f.append(a)
        print("Thanks for your bought")
    else:
        print("Code already exist.")
def Sell():
    return 0
def Calculate():
    return 0
def Change():
    return 0
def Determ():
    return 0
s=True
d={'1': Buy, '2': Sell, '3': Calculate, '4': Change,'5':Determ}
while(s==True):
    print("""this the farm's menu
    1.register a purchase
    2.Register a sale
    3.Calculate profit
    4.Change age
    5.Determ
    6.exit
    """)
    a=input("Choose your option: ")
    if(a==6):
        s=False
    else:
        d[a]();
```

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Lo hice un tanto diferente pero igual me sirvió, muchas gracias bro